I have a problem fixing border radius in tailwind/nextjs
I would like to ask for help with my project nextjs/tailwind. The active slide (first image from left-right) should have a rounded right border.
Image of the slide, the right borders of active slide remain unchanged!, they should be rounded
            <SwiperSlide key={index} className='relative inset-0 z-5 '>
                      {({isActive})=>(
                          <div className={`overflow-hidden w-full h-[500px] mb-[100px] bg-pink-400 relative shadow-gray-500 shadow-xl transition-all duration-500 rounded-3xl ${isActive ? "rounded-l-full rounded-r-3xl" : ""}`}>
                                <div className={`absolute inset-0 flex justify-center h-[350px] flex-row transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out mb-[150px]`}>
                                  <Image src={image.src}
                                  fill
                                  style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
                                  alt='travel images'
                                  className={`w-full rounded-3xl ${isActive?"rounded-r-3xl":""}`}
                                  />
                                </div>
                                <div className='absolute top-2/3 px-[50px] pt-10'>
                                  <div className='text-2xl text-sky-600 font-semibold text-center'>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur </div>
                                  <div className={`text-lg opacity-40 ${isActive? "pl-24" : "" }`}>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil dignissimos repellendus voluptate accusantium deserunt! 
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                      )}
                  </SwiperSlide>

I have tried different ways to make the right border rounded 3xl but no avail.
If I replace rounded-r-full in isActive , the active slide both left and right borders will change but otherwise its right border remains the same. Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks a lot!!!

Just the method to fix such things_ start with a very simple prototype and add ever more features. Then in the browser's develop window (F12 or such) check for errors. Often it is the wrong level of nesting, tackling the wrong component or wrong preceding CSS.

Thank you Joop, I thought your answer was not really what I needed until I tried it. It is such as simple thing yet I didn't think of it before. It works! I changed the border radius to specific number. Thank you again
